# Сказуемое в предложении "В нашем обществе это непозволительно"

Tags: синтаксис

Проверьте, пожалуйста, правильно ли это: я определила его как выраженное наречием *непозволительно*, нулевая связка-глагол отсутствует. Верно?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Случай непростой.

В Вашем предложении НЕПОЗВОЛИТЕЛЬНО - краткое прилагательное, а не наречие, ибо является сказуемым при подлежащем ЭТО. Это (каково?) НЕПОЗВОЛИТЕЛЬНО.

Ср.: Опаздывать будет непозволительно! Здесь НЕПОЗВОЛИТЕЛЬНО - предикативное наречие.

Comment: ayy ladies, Вы меня запутали совсем : ) суммирую: в МОЕМ предложении сказуемое выражено кратким прилагательным, глагол-связка опущена, так?

Comment: Так. Вы правы, в Вашем примере составное именное сказуемое выражено кратким прилагательным, глагол-связка опущена.

Comment: поняла, большое спасибо! : )

Answer (score 2):

К уже сказанному добавлю еще **третью синтаксическую функцию** слова "непозволительно", это **непредикативное (обычное) наречие в роли обстоятельства образа действия или степени**:

(1)И почему-то это всё совпало с днями победы, что особенно обидно, **непозволительно обидно**.

(2) Наши поезда ― или пароходы, если точнее, ― давно разошлись, а прощальные гудки **непозволительно затянулись**.